# Regex - accept value between 5 and 555

Tags: regex

I have a text box. This text box should accept only values between 5 and 555. But I am unable to achieve it.

I have tried the below:

```
/^[0-9]{5, 500}$/
```

Kindly help me in this case.

Comment: Why regex?! A couple of arithmetic comparisons would be better.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: i am using C#. According to system architecture , I need to do it with regex only. Kindly help me please.

Comment: @AkkiBhogte Is it 500 or 555?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need:

```
^([5-9]|\d\d|[1-4]\d\d|5[0-4]\d|55[0-5])$
```

It uses `|` to have 3 different statements to deal with 1-digit, 2-digit and 3-digit numbers.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/iL5qJ1/2)</kbd>

How it works:

```
^          # String starts with ...
(
  [5-9]      # 1-Digit - Any digit 5 or over (5 to 9)
  |          # OR
  \d\d       # 2-Digit - Any 2 digits (since any 2-digit number will be within your range)
  |          # OR
  [1-4]\d\d  # 3-Digit (below 500) - Any digit 1 to 5 (100 to 500), followed by any 2 digits
  |          # OR
  5[0-4]\d   # 3-Digit (above 500, below 550) - 5, followed by any digit 0 to 4 (500 to 540),
             # followed by any digit
  |          # OR
  55[0-5]    # 3-Digits (550 or above) - 55, followed by any digit 0 to 5 (550 to 555)
)
$          # ... String ends with
```

Comment: @Druzion Thank you very much..!

Answer (score 3):

This should work (though not recommended)

```
^(55[0-5]|5[0-4][0-9]|[1-4][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[5-9])$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mX2eE9/3)**

**[Proof of correctness](http://ideone.com/gM4waF)**

Comment: For proof +1! Nice idea!

Comment: @Akki Bhogte consider accepting the answer if it helped